# Select distinct column, and a count of the entries

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a database table which stores competition entries from users.

I am wanting to select distinct email address, and then the number of entries for each email address. So I want to see how many times each email address has been used for entries.

I am thinking something along the lines of

```
SELECT DISTINCT `email` FROM `tablename`   but have a count in there somewhere?
```

Sorry, probably a very basic question really. But I can't seem to get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
SELECT email, COUNT(*) totalCount
FROM tableName
GROUP BY email
```

This will give you unique set of `email` and give you the total records for the specific `email`.

`COUNT()` is an aggregate function which basically count the number of records for each group if `GROUP BY` is specified, in this case `email`, but if no `GROUP BY` then it will count all records in the table.

Comment: That is perfect! I knew it was actually really simple. Oops!

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (`email` varchar(10));

INSERT INTO tbl (`email`)
VALUES
    ('a@b.com'),
    ('b@b.com'),
    ('c@b.com'),
    ('d@b.com'),
    ('e@b.com'),
    ('a@b.com'),
    ('b@b.com'),
    ('c@b.com'),
    ('c@b.com');

SELECT email, COUNT(*)
FROM tbl
GROUP BY email;
```

Result

```
|   EMAIL | COUNT(*) |
----------------------
| a@b.com |        2 |
| b@b.com |        2 |
| c@b.com |        3 |
| d@b.com |        1 |
| e@b.com |        1 |
```

[See a demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/16970/1)